# Install backsplash before upgrading countertops

Tags: kitchen-counters, backsplash

The granite countertops I'm considering for future kitchen plans are 3cm in thickness, it is my understanding they are mounted flat onto the tops of the cabinets, as I presume my existing laminate ones are.

My current backsplash area is prepped and ready for tile.

Can I go ahead and tile the backsplash accounting for enough room for the future countertops/caulking so that my newly installed drywall is protected from grease/water/stains?

The countertop installers acted like this isn't as uncommon as I thought it'd be. They said occasionally they can use 2cm countertops or cut a bit of the tiling off if need-be.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, but it leaves you open to a less perfect fit. Backsplashes have much more flexibility of position than a granite top, so the latter should really be installed first. You don't want anyone trying to cut tile after it's installed. That sounds like a risky proposition with respect to quality.

I'd prime and paint your drywall and wait.